# iPad Air 2 Won't Take Screenshots

Tags: ios

Screenshot no longer works on my iPad Air 2. Tried turning on/off, resetting, resetting settings, rebooting. Both the home button and power button work individually and my iPad used to take screenshots. How can get my iPad to take screenshots again.

Comment: so the Press the Power and Home buttons at the same time is not working any more?

Comment: Thats correct. Used to work pressing power and home buttons together but now does not work. iPad is only 6mths old. Had a lot of problems with iPad shutting off by itself but think I have solved this by deleting Messenger app, Thanks Mary

Comment: And each of them works fine individually (Power and Home)

Comment: Yes they both work individually

Comment: Can you take a screenshot with AssistiveTouch? Enable it in Settings>General>Accessibility.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Problem sorted. It was nearing full capacity so I deleted unused apps and did a full reset and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot happens when both of the buttons are released at the same time, so if you can slow down your movements and hold down the buttons for a short "two count" or long "one count" - basically a second and a half, then release both precisely.

If that doesn't work, you either have full storage or a problem with the system being able to process the button release events in a timely manner.

To troubleshoot that:

1. Put the device in AirPlane mode and power it off.
2. Power on the device and don't connect to any networks.
3. Open Storage and make sure you have 1 GB free or more.
4. Delete apps, connect to iTunes and make a backup if you have nothing you can afford to delete long term.
5. Once you have enough space free - try taking a screen shot in AirPlane mode.
6. If that still fails - erase all content and settings on the device (or restore it over USB from iTunes or similar tool.
7. If the screen shot still doesn't work after deleting all your content or restoring - seek service - there's something wrong with the hardware.

Depending on how much you deleted - restore your backup to the repaired / replaced / restored iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Since both buttons work individually, of course it has to be a software issue.[Backing up your iPad with iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/KM205110?cid=acs::applesearch) and then [restoring the backup with iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201252) is a great place to start when dealing with persistent iOS issues (click the links for help, as the link to Apple Support articles).

Answer (score -1):

My iPad 2 seemed to stop performing screen shots after 10.0.1 spoftware update. Tried all remedies suggested, even resetting. To no avail. Then whilst trying again to take screenshot found the solution. It now takes different actions to do screenshot. Now I have to press both buttons simultaneously, then release power button, screen goes blank and then clicks giving a screenshot. Prior to this I just pressed home button first then pressed power button like you would a camera shutter button. Prefer the previous action, seems more natural.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions. To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).  Flagging for removal as not an answer.